# Form not passing IP address

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I have three forms: 
1. Enters in the port number (form 2)
2. Enters in the IP address (form 3)
3. Launches the client socket (form 1)

The port number is being successfully passed and I am able to move the form 2. However, form 2 on the click of the "ok" button gives an error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The requested address
>   is not valid in its context 127.0.0.0:0 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)

Port Form OK Button Handler (Form 2)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OBJ As New Form3
    OBJ.Port = txtSend.Text
    OBJ.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

IP Address Form OK Button Handler (Form 3)

```
Public Property Port As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OBJ As New Form1
    OBJ.IP = txtSend.Text
    OBJ.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

The function where the IP address and port number should be passed (Form 1)

```
Public Property Port As String
Public Property IP As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    mobjClient = New TcpClient(IP, CInt(Port))
    DisplayText("Connected to host" & vbCrLf)

    mobjClient.GetStream.BeginRead(marData, 0, 1024, AddressOf DoRead, Nothing)

    Send("New client online")
End Sub
```

Comment: where is the `Port` property being set?

Comment: Updated the question. It is being set in its own form similar to the IP Address

Comment: that's setting the property on an object of type `Form3`; if the object in your last snippet actually the `Form1` class?

Comment: Yes that is form 1

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line where the arrow is.

IP Address Form OK Button Handler (Form 3)

```vb
Public Property Port As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OBJ As New Form1
    OBJ.IP = txtSend.Text
    OBJ.Port = Port '<<=====
    OBJ.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```